# Visualizing Freebase data with F# (Type Providers)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

With F#, I have used the FreeBase type provider (FSharp.Data) to play around with random data and I'm having trouble visualizing the data that comes back. As I use a (WPF-based) `DataGrid` and I then populate the `ItemsSource`with a collection of something (Chemical Elements, Stars etc.)

What I'm getting is that when the `DataGrid` is populated, it 'skips' some properties of that entity that I want to visualize, for example the MainImage which every entity has. Other properties of type IEnumerable of string are also not being visualized.

"not being visualized", means there is no column being created for that property.

in a demo video of F# by Don Syme I see he is using the same thing (a DataGird with WPF) 
here's the demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SGPEUuG1I8 (6 min) I'm not sure whether he was using a customized grid! I had expected, looking at that grid, that it was the default one! as it renders all properties in a non-fancy way!

Code I used to show data with WPF

```
open System.Windows
open System.Xaml
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Media

let main = new Window()
main.Height <- 600.0
main.Width <- 500.0

let grid = new DataGrid()
grid.SetValue(DataGrid.FontSizeProperty,20.0)  
main.Content <- grid

let show data =
     match main.IsLoaded with
     | true -> grid.ItemsSource <- data
     | false -> main.Show(); grid.ItemsSource <- data
```

and I use it like this:

```
freebase.Commons.Astronomy.Stars |> Seq.take 10 |> show
```

data retrieval works fine, the grid does not render all stuff! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The used ad-hoc data binding `grid.ItemsSource <- data` silently assumes that the underlying type of items in `data` collection allows reasonable rendering of each column value into grid cell. But such assumption is too strong to always be the true!

Bound expression `freebase.Commons.Astronomy.Stars |> Seq.take 10` has type 
`seq<FreebaseData.ServiceTypes.Astronomy.Astronomy.StarData>`. In turn, `StarData` properties may be anything. For example, property `Also known as` constitutes `IEnumerable` by itself, etc. How it should be rendered to a grid cell by default?

If instead we provide a data projection that ensures a default visualization for the binding, then everything would be OK. For example, showing names and distances to five closest to Earth stars can be projected like below:

```
let astronomy = data.``Science and Technology``.Astronomy
let fiveClosestStars =
    query { for e in astronomy.Stars do
               where e.Distance.HasValue 
               sortBy e.Distance.Value
               take 5
               select (e.Name, e.Distance) }
```

where `fiveClosestStars` now has `DataGrid`-palatable type
`Linq.IQueryable<string * Nullable<float<Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitNames.metre>>>`. Then binding

```
grid.ItemsSource <- fiveClosestStars
```

yields the expected visual experience

> Sun                     149597987918.808
>   Proxima Centauri 4.014161112E+16
>   Wolf 359              7.3747752E+16
>   Sirius                   8.1461952E+16
>   Altair                    1.58295384E+17

Comment: this works fine with strings and integers but in case of the type ImageData (SomeEntity.MainImage) all i get is a url to that image, but this won't render in a DataGrid impicitly!

Comment: I'm not aware of the ability of WPF DataGrid to implicitly bind images to columns. AFAIK in the demo by Don Syme you referred in your question such functionality was backed up by
100-smth lines of F# custom binding code. You may want exploring `show-wpf40.fsx` from
[a similar demo sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-22-06-15/BuildDemo.zip) for the further details.